# Excel: Is it possible to select multiple values in Drop-down list? (without VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there any possibility to mark more values in drop-down list and to have them in one single row?

This is the way I found but still it is not inside a single row...

[My DDT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwQqz.gif)

And this is actually what I would like to have but WITHOUT VBA if possible..

[With VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfOfH.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy.

Here is an example.  Setup *DV* in cell **B1** using a list in column **D**:

[image]

Then copy cell **B1** downward *(each of the copied cells will also have DV)*

In **C1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B:B)
```

Then make your selection(s) in the **B** cells:

[image]

**NOTE:**

This technique:

- allows as many items as you want to be concatenated
- allows the same item to be concatenated more than one time.
- assumes you are using a version of Excel that supports `TEXTJOIN()`
- does not rely on VBA

Comment: Man!! WTH! This is mind blowing and super easy :/  You made my Blue Monday m8!! Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: @Mirza  You are quite welcome.................we are, in effect, treating a small block of cells like a multiSelect ListBox

Comment: It worked at home (using Office 365) but here in my Company is O2016 and I dont have this function at all. Maybe to try combo; text and concatenate?

Comment: ACtually I could get similar using: =CONCATENATE(C2&" ";C3&" ";C4&" ";C5&" ";C6&" ";C7&" ";C8&" ")   or '=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15&" "&C16&" "&C17&" "&C18&" "&C19&" "&C20&" "&C21);" ";", ")

Both also works...